# CSV field with less than max cell limit of excel is getting truncated

Tags: c#, excel, csv, export-to-csv

We are trying to export data to a CSV file via C# code. Some of the fields are really long and exceeds the max character limit of an excel's cell can support (32,767) as per this [site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). So what we did is to truncate any data in excess of the limit. However, when we tried opening the CSV file in excel, it placed some bits of characters below even though the text length inside the cell didn't reach the limit. I have [attached](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FSwh0Pvpv4-heXtimhfr9R6Hsry8q9SU) a sample CSV file. Kindly download and open in excel.[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cm9g4QmE7k6aH_DXNQop3HqwYMPOd_Zl). The csv field has a character limit of 32,766 including the begin and end double quotes.

Comment: Is the value you're writing in the cell correct, or is that one already a couple of characters off...? And are you able to add characters to that cell manually? Just to get a clear idea of where the issue seems to be... It would help if you post some code by the way :)

Comment: Excel sounds like the wrong place to store this.

Comment: The value on that cell is just a test data to demo the weird behavior. Yes I am able to add characters to the CSV files using C#. My concern is that even though the character length is below the max limit, Excel seems not able to interpret it correctly.

Comment: Check if the max number of characters that is being stored in the cell is constant. If so, adapt your code to truncate in the verified max char count.

Comment: @BugFinder I know. But the client needs to use excel features (sorting, filtering, etc)

Comment: Well, as better alternatives than Excel, you could suggest to your client to use MS Access or LibreOffice Base, or you could create a program to meet the client needs.

Comment: @Magnetron as much as I would like to suggest those. The client won't agree. What I tried is to further reduce the limit to only allow characters up to 32.7K and it worked. I am thinking that the 32,767 limit only applies to real "excel" file types and not on CSVs.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be a problem during the csv parse that excel does, because after you open it you can add character until the specified limit.

Answer (score 1):

Excel appears to have a limit of **32,758 characters** per cell when importing a CSV file, despite [the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) saying that the limit is 32,767 characters. In other words, having 32,759 or more characters in a cell will cause problems when the CSV is imported.

Escaped double quotes (`""`) only count as a single character for this purpose.

The two double quotes that surround the cell content (if needed) don't count toward the limit.

Unix style newlines (`\n`) count as one character while Windows style newlines (`\r\n`) count as two characters. Note that, even if you specify Unix style newlines (`\n`) in your code, some functions/languages may automatically convert them to Windows style newlines (`\r\n`), which may then cause some of your otherwise valid cells to exceed the limit. Here's how to avoid that issue in several different languages:

- **C#:** Use `\n` instead of `Environment.NewLine`.
- **C++ (fopen)**: Open the file in binary mode using the `b` flag in the `mode` parameter: `fopen("filename", "wb")`.
- **C++ (ofstream)**: Use binary mode when opening the file for writing: `std::ofstream outfile("filename", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out)`.
- **Java**: Use `\n` instead of `System.lineSeparator()`.
- **Python (io.open)**: Use `newline='\n'` in your call to `io.open`.